# Липучесть заголовка приходится настраивать несколько раз

Tags: предложение

Хорошо бы вообще один раз для всех сайтов сети поставить и всё, а тут приходится дважды на одном выставлять - на основном и на мете.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Возможность тонкой настройки же! Надо еще ник сделать разный для меты и основного.